# How do I trigger focus on an antd input inside a Form.Item from the onPressEnter call back?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I have an antd table that is populated by editable cells and one of these cells is a Form.Item and this Item holds an input surrounded by a tooltip. I want this tooltip to trigger in case the account number entered into it is already in use.

So basically:

1. A new account number is put into the input
2. If the account number is already taken it is not saved

- The account number is saved using setTakenAccountNumber
- The isAccountNumber variable is saved using isAccountNumberTaken
- This is when I want the tooltip to trigger but it doesn't, because the input
  has lost focus

3. If the account not is not taken it is saved and everything is well

So my question is - how do I re-focus the input to allow the tooltip to trigger?

Here is the code:

```
    const EditableCell = ({ title, editable, children, dataIndex, account, handleSave, testing, ...restProps }) => {
        const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
        const inputRef = useRef(null);
        const form = useContext(EditableContext);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (editing && inputRef && inputRef.current) {
                inputRef.current.focus();
            }
        }, [editing]);

        if (account != null && account.associated_account_id != null) {
            editable = dataIndex !== "name" && dataIndex !== "account_number" ? false : true;
        }

        const toggleEdit = () => {
            setEditing(!editing);
            form.setFieldsValue({
                [dataIndex]: account.group_id === 5 ? account.account[dataIndex] : account[dataIndex],
            });
        };

        const checkIsAccountTaken = async (e) => {
            const accountNumber = e.target.value;
            const identicalAccount = [];
            fetchAllAccountsByNumber(accountNumber, identicalAccount, props.accountStructure);

            const isAccountNumberTaken = identicalAccount.length > 0;

            if (!isAccountNumberTaken) {
                save();
                setIsAccountNumberTaken(false);

            } else {
                form.setFieldsValue({
                    [dataIndex]: accountNumber,
                });

                setTakenAccountNumber(accountNumber);
                setIsAccountNumberTaken(isAccountNumberTaken);
            }
        }

        const save = async () => {
            try {
                const values = await form.validateFields();

                toggleEdit();
                handleSave({ ...account, ...values });

            } catch (errInfo) {
                // console.log("Save failed:", errInfo);
            }
        };

        let childNode = children;
        
        if (editable) {
            if (dataIndex.slice(0, 6) === "period") {
                childNode = (
                    <div
                        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                        style={{
                            height: 24,
                            width: 150,
                            padding: 0,
                        }}
                        onClick={toggleEdit}>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                childNode = editing ? (
                    // <Tooltip visible={isAccountNumberTaken} placement="top" title={<span>{"Account Number Already In Use"}</span>}>
                        <Form.Item
                            tooltip={<div>123</div>}
                            style={{
                                margin: 0,
                            }}
                            name={dataIndex}
                            rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: `${title} is required.`,
                                },
                            ]}>
                                <Input ref={inputRef} onPressEnter={(e) => checkIsAccountTaken(e, this)} onBlur={checkIsAccountTaken} />    
                        </Form.Item>
                    // </Tooltip>
                ) : (
                    <div
                        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                        style={{
                            paddingLeft: 10,
                            paddingBottom: 3,
                        }}
                        onClick={toggleEdit}>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
```